# Next.js Reload Web Page

Tags: javascript, web, next.js, web-applications, next.js13

Can I reload the web page of my client through the server at specific time?

I want to reload my client's page at 12pm. I am using scheduler, but the web page of the client side isn't refreshing automatically.

[You can see my code API is working but the web page is not reloading itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD0E1.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: why don't you just add that logic in client code to reload itself at 12 pm

Comment: where to put it in client side using next.js 12. something

Comment: You should not post code (or errors/exceptions, logs, configuration, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Refresh client component and render in the page which you want to reload/refresh

```js
// @/components/Refresh.jsx
'use client';

import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Refresh({ interval }) {
  const id = useRef('');

  useEffect(() => {
    id.current = setInterval(() => {
      // add your logic here to match 12 pm with current time and then reload
      window.location.reload();
    }, interval);
    return () => clearInterval(id.current);
  }, [id.current, interval]);
  return null;
}

// @/app/layout.jsx for all pages
// @/app/page.jsx for just homepage

<Refresh interval={60*1000} />
```